# How to save selected options in datatables when we move to the next page of pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, html

I want to the selected options to be in checked state even if i go to the next page and the come back to the same page. I am using datatable in this. Is there any way to perform this action?

Comment: I don't see any table in your question

Comment: You need to store the state of the checkboxes somewhere. A cookie, localStorage, the server side session or database are all viable solutions. I'd suggest searching as this has been asked and answered *a lot* of times previously.

Answer (score 0):

you can get selected options from datatables on click of submit button. please refer the following js code.

`var table = $("#data_table_id").dataTable();`
`var selected_options = $.map(table.$('input:checked'), function(ele) {return ele.value;});`

then you can set selected_options to some hidden field so that it will get passed through params. Then you can process the params and can save it to database.